# Is there an alternative to using the global keyword?

Tags: python

I'm still learning python and wondering if thiers a better way of converting a local variable to a global variable, without VSC saying thiers two problems?

```
def square (x):
    global y
    y = x * x
    return y

square(10)

print(10 + y)
```

[image]

Comment: just remove the `global y`, then `y` is a local variable, and use `y = square(10)`

Comment: you don't seem to understand what python is telling you. you can't use a variable if its not declared or assigned before.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a misconception around the `global` keyword. When you use `global`, you are telling the interpreter you want to use the outermost `y` variable instead of the local scope one.

Take this example:

```py
y = 3

def change_global():
  ''' Any changes to y inside this function will also change y globally ''' 
  global y 
  y += 1

def change_local():
  ''' Here y is a local variable, thus any changes will not propagate globally '''
  y = 0
  y += 100 # No effect globally, y is local

  
change_global()
print(y) # prints 4

change_local()
print(y) # prints 4

change_global()
print(y) # prints 5
```

In your example you are trying to use a variable before it has been declared. If you want `y` to be accessed anywhere in your code, you have to initialize it beforehand. However this is not a very good practice. I would recommend just removing the `global` keyword from your function and saving the result to operate on it further on:

```py
def square(x):
  return x * x  

s = square(10)
print(10 + s)
```

Comment: I just want to reinforce what Diego is telling you here, and what rioV8 said in the question's comments. Avoid using the global keyword altogether. Specially if you're learning how to program right now.

The global keyword should be used only in special cases when implementing some advanced techniques, or else your code will become a nasty spaghetti quickly!

If you want to access global variables inside functions, pass them as parameters. If you want to access results from your function in the global scope, pass the results back to the global scope using the "return" keyword instead!